# Samba4 Domain and Active Directory compatibility?

Tags: windows, samba, active-directory

I'm running a testing AD lab at home which has a AD forest with single domain. The functional level is 2016. I'm trying to move to Samba4 domain controllers for licensing issues and also testing new stuff. Before begin, I'm wondering how compatible it is with the existing Windows infrastructure? The current infrastructure is listed below:

- One Windows Server 2019 Domain Controller
- One forest (Functional level 2019), one domain
- Several sites (currently I'm only using one)
- Several GPO (10 ~ 20 I think?)
- ADCS
- <= 5 users
- SQL Server (Installed on a domain-joined Windows Server with AD auth)
- WSUS, NPS, SMB File share, etc (several domain-joined servers)
- A two-node Hyper-V Failover Cluster.
- AAD Connect
- Currently there's no System Center products.
- One or two Windows 10 PCs.
- Using RSAT for administrating.

Will they work as-is if I switch to Samba DC, or will there be any compatibility issues? How about file ACLs? How about administrating costs (like simple management and troubleshooting, rich community resources, easy upgrading, etc)? Is it possible to switch to Samba directly or do I need to create a new domain or forest? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, Samba 4.15 only supports **Server 2008 functional level**, so you most likely won't be able to add Samba DCs to your existing domain. You also won't be able to add a new domain to the forest.

Other than that, there might be some compatibility problems depending on the Samba version – I would very strongly recommend 4.12 or later. Here's the overall status around Samba 4.15:

- Samba *does* support joining an existing domain as a DC and replicating data, but even if you start fresh with a Samba-only domain you'll want a recent version with all the replication-related fixes.
- Samba *does not* implement **AD Web Services**, which means PowerShell AD cmdlets will not work. However, RSAT *does* work as it only needs traditional MS-RPC and LDAP. (PowerShell's `[adsi]` interface is also LDAP-based, so it works too.)

  - (I seem to remember that promoting Server2012+ as a DC appears to require AD Web Services for some reason, so that won't work either... so if you want to migrate from Samba to Windows Server, you might need to use Server2008 as an intermediary.)
- File ACLs *will* work fine, as do registry ACLs, printer ACLs, GPO ACLs, etc. All of them are enforced by file servers themselves, not by the DCs (the DC just has to report your group memberships correctly).
- AD Certificate Services *will* work, but it's not a DC feature and not included as part of Samba – you will still need Windows Server to actually host the certification authority.

  - Also note that older Samba DC versions (up to 4.12) had a bug which prevented computers from being automatically granted "**Domain Computer**" SID, which affected all types of ACLs. Most importantly it meant AD Certificate Services auto-enrolment wouldn't work, because many standard certificate template ACLs require "Domain Computer". (This bug was fixed in 4.13+ so ADCS now works correctly, as do all other ACL types.)
- Group Policies *will* work. However, the GPO data won't automatically sync across multiple DCs (because Samba lacks DFS-R support), so you'll need to manually robocopy your Sysvol after every change. (But note the "Domain Computer" ACL bug.)
- Azure AD Connect *probably* won't work.
- I'm not sure whether Kerberos constrained delegation is implemented fully, which may be relevant to Hyper-V clusters.
- Standalone Hyper-V works. Replication works. Live migration *almost* works – there's a small bug (all the way to 4.16) that prevents Samba DCs from correctly issuing Kerberos tickets if the SPN contains spaces.

  (Fortunately, Hyper-V live migration is the only service that thought it would be a good idea to put spaces in its SPNs. There is a manual workaround, though, *and* there is a patch on Bugzilla as well, but it hasn't been applied yet.)
- No idea whether Hyper-V clustering works or not – it might be affected by the "spaces in SPN" bug, as well as lack of constrained delegation.

Comment: FWIW Samba docs claim that v4.10+ support AD Schema version up to v69 (aka Win Server 2012r2). https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/AD_Schema_Version_Support Is that incorrect or are you mistaken?

Comment: @JeremyDavis: Schema version is not functional level – it only defines what LDAP attributes can be _stored,_ but doesn't say anything about what protocol features (which need new code) are supported, e.g. "Password Settings Objects" were part of the 2008 schema since the beginning of 4.0, but the DC code to actually understand them was only added in 4.9. (Similarly, Kerberos FAST and RBCD is a Server 2012 feature that were only added in Samba 4.17 this year...) Seems like it's actually possible to make Samba claim 2012_R2 functional level, but I'm not sure if it'll behave correctly.

Comment: thanks for the detail, muchly appreciated! :)